# Check MSWord is Installed in system

Tags: c#, ms-word

Exact Duplicate:

> [**C#: How to know whether certain Office 2003 or 2007 application is installed?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531659/c-how-to-know-whether-certain-office-2003-or-2007-application-is-installed)

How to check if MSWord 2003 0r 2007 is installed in the system using C# code?

Comment: http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+How%20to%20check%20if%20MSWord%202003%200r%202007%20is%20installed%20in%20the%20system%20using%20C%23%20code%3F

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This code](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18725) shows that a simple registry check will do the job.

Here is the code converted to C# (and slightly improved to use a `using` statement).

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

// Check whether Microsoft Word is installed on this computer,
// by searching the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application key.
using (var regWord = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Word.Application"))
{
    if (regWord == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Word is not installed");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Word is installed");
    }
}
```

Note that it's not good enough to check `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\` for the `msword` EXE file, as the user might have installed it somewhere else.

Comment: How can I get the version 2003 or 2007?

Comment: Is there any way to check same from Desktop Browser using Javascript or Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution, i reckon there should be better if you google it.
To Check whether Excel is installed or not, I use this c# code

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

if `app == null` that means excel is not installed on the machine.If you check the MSDN docs, you should be able to get the syntax for opening a word appln.

Comment: I have the syntax for opening a word document. But if word is not installed.............

Comment: I thought the new-operator returns an object in every case. So 'app' can't be null, right? There might be an exception if Word is not installed but I don't know yet.