# Find out if an executable is installed and programatically open it

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a code that when I say open a program, it will open. But, what if that program doesn't exist? How can I make my code tell me it doesn't exist? And, how can I make my code open an alternative program if it exist?

```
case "open microsoft word":
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.exe");
                JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
                break;
```

Answer (score 5):

That's kind of a [brittle way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897633/check-msword-is-installed-in-system) to check if Word is installed. What if the user installed it in a different path? Does it need to be that particular version of Office? You'd be better off checking the registry I think.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

// Check whether Microsoft Word is installed on this computer,
// by searching the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application key.
using (var regWord = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Word.Application"))
{
    if (regWord == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Word is not installed");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Word is installed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about if Word was installed in a different path. I just didn't know how to go about it. It also does NOT need to be a particular version.

Comment: How would I open the program after checking the registry, regardless of its version?

Comment: `Process.Start("WinWord.exe");` should do it. See this link for more details. http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Comment: Thx so much. Truly was a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.exe")) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat It happens to all of us :(